# How to count the number of forms on a website

Tags: regex, forms, web-crawler

For a project that I am doing, I would like to list or extract all the pages(url) that has a **form** in it. Is there a easy way to do this using Python or another tool? I was thinking along the lines of using a regex to identify some form identifier like <\form> tag, but was not sure if there was better or more efficient way to do this.

Thanks much for anyone with any inputs or ideas.

Comment: Check out beautiful soup. `BeautifulSoup(your_html).find_all("form")` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Using BeautifulSoup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urlparse
soup = BeautifulSoup(fetch('yourUrl.com'))
form = soup.find('form')
```

[For reference](https://gist.github.com/Lukasa/5281176)